# PHP bind_param using variables or POST?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

When using bind_param with a mysqli prepared statement, I am unsure whether to use `$_POST` or variables. If the `bind_param` values come from a form submitted through a website, is it unsafe to put the `$_POST` values straight into the `bind_param`?

```
$newBlog->bind_param('ss',$_POST['newBlogTitle'],$_POST['newBlogContent']);
```

or

```
$newBlogTitle = $_POST['newBlogTitle'];
$newBlogTitle = $_POST['newBlogContent'];
$newBlog->bind_param('ss',$newBlogTitle,$newBlogContent);
```

Or does it not matter?

Comment: it'd only matter if your binding variables for fetching data into. for putting data IN to a query, there's no difference

Comment: Variable content doesn't change because of assigning it to another local variable.

Comment: And PHP variables are copy-on-write anyway, so your new variables are literally referencing the same memory.

Comment: It's not really unsafe but since bound parameters have to be passed by reference ... I'd copy the `$_POST` vars to other variables first and pass those by reference - you can't really write to `$_POST` so this could cause issues if you're attempting to send them to a stored procedure to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> s it unsafe to put the $_POST values straight into the bind_param?

String concatenation is key to SQL injection. However, because you are using parameterized queries the data will be automatically escaped and injection risk will be eliminated. It is irrelevant whether or not you assign the $_POST variable to a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. The values of the variables are the same, since you're just assigning one to the other.